# How to read this xml file in java (need to be done by using exported,firstName,lastName,...)?

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects xmlns="XXXXXXX">
<cuobject type-id="EmailSubscription" object-id="jjjil@gmail.com">
    <object-attribute attribute-id="exported">true</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="firstName">jjj</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="lastName">jjj</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="subscribed">true</object-attribute>
</cuobject>

<cuobject type-id="EmailSubscription" object-id="gggj@gmail.com">
    <object-attribute attribute-id="exported">true</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="firstName">ghh</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="lastName">fhh</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="subscribed">true</object-attribute>
</cuobject>

<cuobject type-id="EmailSubscription" object-id="mmm@gmail.com">
    <object-attribute attribute-id="exported">true</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="firstName">mmm</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="lastName">mmm</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="subscribed">true</object-attribute>
</cuobject>
</objects>
```

How to read this xml file in java (need to be done by using exported,firstName,lastName,...)?
how do we do that?
I am doing it like

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("cuobject");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
{               

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);       

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());         

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
    {        

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        String email = eElement.getAttribute("object-id");

        String firstName =  eElement.

        getElementsByTagName("object-attribute").item(1).getTextContent();

        String lastName = eElement.

        getElementsByTagName("object-attribute").item(2).getTextContent();

        String subscribed = eElement.

        getElementsByTagName("object-attribute").item(3).getTextContent();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about alternative methods to the one you already use?

Comment: ya got one ,now using one suggested by @SRT_KP..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, if you have no problem with JAXB

1. Convert your xml to XSD.

   You can convert xml to XSD online such as (http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)
2. Convert XSD to Java Class

   if you are using eclipse juno you can easily convert it schema to Java class. check out for the detailed step here (http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-in-eclipse-ide/)
3. Use the XML as an object( in line to OOPS, which suites very well to your customer details XML) to access the values

   public class MyTestClass {

   ```
   /**
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       File file = new File("C:\\kar\\file1.xml");
       try{
       JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Objects.class);
       Unmarshaller jaxbUnMarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();


       Objects listcustomers = (Objects) jaxbUnMarshaller.unmarshal(file);
       List<Cuobject> cusmters=listcustomers.getCuobject();
       Iterator<Cuobject> it = cusmters.iterator();
       while(it.hasNext()){
           Cuobject customer = it.next();
           System.out.println("Customer ID: "+ customer.typeId + " Customer email" + customer.objectId);
           List<ObjectAttribute> details =customer.objectAttribute;
           Iterator<ObjectAttribute> it1 = details.iterator();
           System.out.println(" -------Details------------");
           while(it1.hasNext()){
               ObjectAttribute detail = it1.next();

               System.out.println(detail.attributeId + " =" + detail.value);
           }
       }
       }catch(Exception ex){
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. Output would be something like this

   Customer ID: EmailSubscription Customer emailjjjil@gmail.com
    -------Details------------
   exported =true
   firstName =jjj
   lastName =jjj
   subscribed =true

   ```
   Customer ID: EmailSubscription Customer emailgggj@gmail.com
    -------Details------------
   exported =true
   firstName =ghh
   lastName =fhh
   subscribed =true
   Customer ID: EmailSubscription Customer emailmmm@gmail.com
    -------Details------------
   exported =true
   firstName =mmm
   lastName =mmm
   subscribed =true
   ```

Comment: hi i have eclipse juno but dont know where is "com.sun.tools.xjc.[version number].jar" and "com.sun.xml.bind.[version number].jar",i have "plugins\javax.xml.bind_2.1.9.v201005080401.jar"

Comment: i am following steps to create java class from xsd and stuck there got an error saying "unrecognized parameter -target"

Comment: No need of adding those jar files... skip that step and follow rest all steps..........

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,Ok following steps again

Comment: u need to click once on up arrow on the left hand side of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Xml Document using XPath queries and Java Supports them.

You can refer [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java) for more information